# Taking vacations days in the middle of a semester

Tags: teaching, time-off

Context: I am an assistant professor at a small institution in the US.

Question: My significant other has the opportunity through work to travel to an exotic location over a long weekend in February, and I would very much like to join.  That said, it would require that I miss both my Thursday and Friday classes before the weekend.  Would it be unreasonable and/or unprofessional for me to join her on this trip?

I can easily structure my content schedule in such a way that I could cancel these classes without losing anything significant, but I'm concerned about how such an absence would be perceived by my colleagues.  I have an excellent relationship with those in my department, my department chair, and my dean.

I would also be curious to hear how dependent the answer is upon my tenure status.  I am tenure-track and plan to apply for tenure three years from now.

Comment: You need to discuss this with your chair.  In many places, taking personal vacation during the academic term is considered unacceptable, although canceling class to participate in a conference might be OK.  Ultimately the answer will depend on local norms and rules.

Comment: I am not a professor, but it would seem to me the best/expected solution would be to find a substitute instructor (perhaps a graduate student) for those two days instead of cancelling outright.

Comment: This depends on sooo many factors... I would say "yeah, no problem, go ahead", but as @BrianBorchers mentioned, in some places this might be outright unacceptable.

Comment: Some have colleagues who always move classes on Fridays without good reason except they want a longer weekend...

Answer (score 4):

In the departments I have worked in, it would probably be considered unprofessional to leave on a pleasure-cruise in the middle of the semester. I suspect that that is universal.

In other words, this is not the image you want to project as someone who will still have to go through the tenure process. On the other hand, it's a fairly small thing -- people are gone all the time, although almost always for professional reasons: at conferences, workshops, for collaborations. So the mechanics of being gone are all appreciated in any department, such as moving classes around, giving out reading assignments instead of in-person classes, or putting a midterm exam on such a date and having someone else proctor the exam. Students also understand these things. In the end, it will be a judgment call: It comes over as "frivolous" to leave for a vacation and cancel classes over it, but it's also not a huge deal and I'd be surprised if anyone would think that you'll lose tenure over it. It's just a bad mark in your peers' perception of your professionalism.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I’d suggest leaving questions of *perception* aside. It is much more helpful to think whether your suggested behavior *is* unprofessional than to worry about how it will be perceived by your colleagues. But for the first question, don’t just think about superficialities like whether you have the technical ability to reschedule or cancel class or ask a colleague or TA to give it in your place. You need to go deeper than that. Ask yourself:

- Am I potentially inconveniencing my students by redesigning my class schedule to fit my own personal vacation plans? Can I really claim to have my students’ best interest at heart when I say I can “easily structure my content schedule ... without losing anything significant”? (The word “significant” here suggests to me the answer is no.)
- Is the TA or colleague whom I’m thinking of asking to cover my class while I’m on vacation equally qualified as me to give those lectures? Will the students benefit equally from hearing this lecture from the TA/colleague as they would if I were present to deliver it? (Again, I’m guessing the answer is likely no.)
- Will my absence also inconvenience my students in other ways because I’ll have to cancel or reschedule office hours, and be less available to answer their questions over email while I’m on vacation?

You can go even deeper and think about second- and third-order effects of the vacation plan:

- Will my behavior contribute to a healthy departmental and institutional climate? Do I feel comfortable with the thought that my behavior might push norms in the direction of faculty members generally doing whatever they want based on their own convenience, without oversight, without regard to university policies, and without considering the larger picture of the students’ interests? (E.g., perhaps you are acting in a thoughtful way and making sure you’re not hurting the students, but a colleague who sees you behave in this way and might be tempted to behave similarly in the future may not be as thoughtful as you.)
- Will taxpayers in my state feel happy hearing about my behavior, should it get covered by a local newspaper? Can my behavior conceivably cause reputational problems for my department or university?
- Etc.

The bottom line is that to behave professionally is to show yourself as a person who understands that they are being paid to perform a job, and that that job entails certain responsibilities that must be taken very seriously. If you can consider all the questions I listed above and come up with serious, sincere, well-thought out answers to all of them that demonstrate convincingly that your vacation plan is not going to create any inconvenience or negative effects for your students or anyone else, I for one will be more than happy to say you’re acting professionally and to wish you a fun vacation.

That being said, based on how you phrased your question, I feel it’s premature to conclude that you’ve really taken all the effects of your vacation plan into account in the way I’ve suggested.

Answer (score 2):

In the departments I have worked in, this would be completely fine (provided there is no additional work to your peers). So if you need someone to cover your classes (which probably looks better than cancelling them), let it be someone who is familiar with the material and is sympathetic to you and pay the favor back. People generally understand if you take a short vacation because of a one-time-opportunity like it is in your case. This is especially the case if you are "friends" with your peers.

You might want to consider if there are any rules against this and if other people also did this. But don't be afraid to ask, especially given your good relationsship to your superior.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question for your colleagues and chair. A couple of days probably isn't going to be much of an issue, but it will be frowned upon if only a bit. But people go off to conferences for similar amounts of time.

But even better if you can be available to your students via something like email or a mailing list while you are away.

I would say the equation would change if it were a week and both week ends. Now it starts to be a disadvantage for student learning.

You can also offer to do a makeup for anyone who wants - evenings or week ends or virtually somehow. Or extra office hours.

But first, ask those whose opinions you value. Especially as an assistant professor who will be judged by your peers, partly on your commitment. You might just raise the "opportunity" in the coffee room as a possibility and listen to any opinions that are offered.